# Installed by automatic method and manual way but no luck to run

Tags: java

I installed Java Oracle JDK 8 and OpenJDK 11 on Ubuntu 18.04.1, all processes are good but when I run java it returns error:

```
-bash: /usr/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

The update-alternatives:

```
    (base) a13519@master-node:~$ update-alternatives --display java
java - manual mode
  link best version is /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
  link currently points to /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_271/bin/java
  link java is /usr/bin/java
  slave java.1.gz is /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java - priority 1081
  slave java.1.gz: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/man1/java.1.gz


    (base) a13519@master-node:~$ sudo update-alternatives --config java[sudo] password for a13519: 
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode
* 2            /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_271/bin/java               2         manual mode
```

I put jdk under /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_271

why I am facing this issue? How to fix it?

thx

---

Thanks for your reply. This looks messy, I can't get rid of java-15-oracle which was installed previously and uninstalled.

```
(base) a13519@master-node:~$ echo $PATH
/home/a13519/anaconda2/bin:/home/a13519/anaconda2/condabin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_271/bin:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-15-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-15-oracle/db/bin:/home/a13519/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0/bin:/home/a13519/anaconda2/bin:/home/a13519/anaconda2/condabin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

I want this to be available system wide not only myself. but checked the .profile and .bashrc, i can't find any place the java-15-oracle was set and I kept got the same error message of

```
(base) a13519@master-node:~$ java
-bash: /usr/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to set your environment variables correctly.

Edit the system path file `/etc/profile` using your preferred text editor:

```
sudo vi /etc/profile
```

Add following lines at the end:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME
export JRE_HOME
export PATH
```

Then log out back into Ubuntu to set the paths.

Comment: weird:

(base) a13519@master-node:~$ java
-bash: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_271/bin/java: No such file or directory
(base) a13519@master-node:~$ ls -l /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_271/bin/java
-rwxr-xr-x 1 10143 10143 7332 9月  17 01:05 /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_271/bin/java

Comment: Find the issue, it's a 32bit file buy my Ubuntu is 64.